Can't connect to mobile hotspot networks with ubuntu 24.04
When i try to connect to home wifi connections everything works just as intended, but when i try to connect to ANY mobile hotspot connection, it just won't work, it accepts the password, the prompt disappears for about a minute, and then finally a window shows up saying "Activation of network connection failed".
I've tried manually forgetting the networks, restarting the wifi service, restarting the pc, changing the settings of the hotspot, i've tried with about 10 phones and only 1 seems to work, but only sometimes.
With that said, home connections from a physical router always work.
I'm really confused and I can't seem to find an answer, can anyone help?

Once I tried to make a Windows 10 laptop use a hotspot from my tablet and it didn't work on Windows 10 as well. I didn't try anymore, but this may be an issue on the remote end. Even if it fails with 9 out of 10 phones, it's still possible that issue is in these phones.
